# SQL database structure for Like and DisLike

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I am new to web programming and need some expert advise.
I am using SQL database for one of my website project.
My website will display a list of topics with a Like and Dislike button. Logged in users will be able to click on the Like or dislike button for each topic.
I am able to keep a count of likes and dislikes for each topics. So if a user clicks on a certain topic it will display the number of Likes and Dislikes for that particular topic, however what I am trying to achieve is when someone clicks on a particular Users profile it should display all the topics that user likes or dislikes. 
For example when we click on a users profile in Facebook, it displays all the comments or Likes of that particular user, how do I do something similar to that. I would like to know the data structure to implement this and query the data
Thank you all.
Regards,
Aaf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This is a simple schema you could use. isLike is a boolean, true if it's a like, false if it's a dislike.

To query the total likesdislikes by topic

```
    Select Count(*), Topic,isLike FROM LikesDislikes GROUP BY Topic,isLike
```

For all of a user's liked topics

```
   SELECT topic FROM likesdislikes WHERE userName = 'user' AND isLike = true;
```

And so forth.

Comment: its wrong,
likes or dislikes should be counting the numbers, The 1 which i use is ,
CREATE TABLE `like` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `like` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `un-like` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Comment: How would you have a count for likes and dislikes in such table?

Answer (score 8):

If you have a table of Topics and a table of Users, you would add a table of Likes which links to both.  Something like this:

```
User
----------
ID (int, PK)
Name (string)
etc...

Topic
----------
ID (int, PK)
Title (string)
etc...

Like
----------
ID (int, PK)
UserID (int, FK to User.ID)
TopicID (int, FK to Topic.ID)
IsLike (boolean)
etc...
```

So any time a user "likes" something you add a record to that table setting `IsLike` to `true`.  If they "dislike" something then you add a record to that table setting `IsLike` to `false`.  You can change around the terminology/names/types/etc. but the general idea is the same.  A "like" becomes a linking record between a `User` and a `Topic`.

So when displaying the topic, you just select the count of records from the linking table which are associated with that topic.  And when displaying a user you select the records from the linking table which are associated with that user.

Comment: This is how I would do it as well.

Comment: I think naming the table `votes` would be more fitting, but thank you for this example

Answer (score 0):

You could have three SQL tables:

Topics
Ratings
Users

You could then link the Users table via the Ratings table to the Topics table and do a query:

```
select * from Topics where RatingsUserID = UsersUserID
```

(pseudo code)

Comment: You will have a tough time doing this with only 2 tables. You will need a 3rd cross reference table as described above.

Comment: Please reread. "Topics Ratings Users"